# Jquery selector How To highlight select second addDDetails

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, selector

I'm using Jquery selector.
I have two addDDetails.
When we click on addDDetails, system will highlight pink on second addDDetails ( which I remark [ I want select This!!! ])

I noticed that I click on first addDDetails, system highlight pink wrongly at first addDetails.
How can I click on first addDDetails, system highlight pink on second addDDetails?

Thanks.

```js
$(".addDDetails").click(function () {
  $(this).closest(".Details > div").find(".addDDetails").css("background", "pink")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row Details" style="border-style:solid;">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 textfield">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 textfield">
                 <span class="icon icon--plus addDDetails">+</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11 textfield">
       </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 textfield">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 textfield">
                <span class="icon icon--plus addDDetails">+ [ I want select This!!! ]</span>
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11 textfield">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to find the specified index element and bind the corresponding event handler.

---

Or you can use [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) in class selector to judge the current element index and make corresponding logic.

If the elements are siblings, you could do this:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

If not, you can pass a selector of the set in which to look for the element.

```
var index = $(this).index('your selector');
```

e. g.

```js
const _selector = '.addDDetails';
const _cssName = 'background-color';
$(_selector).click(function() {
  const index = $(this).index(_selector);
  $(_selector).css(_cssName, 'red');
  if (index == 0) {
    $(this).eq(index).css(_cssName, '');
  } else {
    $(_selector).css(_cssName, '');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row Details" style="border-style:solid;">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 textfield">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 textfield">
        <span class="icon icon--plus addDDetails">+</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11 textfield">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 textfield">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 textfield">
        <span class="icon icon--plus addDDetails">+ [ I want select This!!! ]</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11 textfield">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution when click the second + addDDetails, there no highlight pink.
It suppose highlight pink also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer use

> .children('div').eq(1)

```
$(".addDDetails").click(function () { 
     $(this).closest(".Details").children('div').eq(1).find('.addDDetails').length == 1).css("background", "pink"); 
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.